# Execute MySQL's SQL files using .NET

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net

Whenever I make an update to my database (changes in stored procs, changes in tables, new tables ,etc.), I create a new sql file which I run on client's computer via TeamViewer.

I wanted my application to update its own database. So I decided to make it download sql files via ftp then updates itself using ExecuteNonQuery or something.

Unfortunately I'm stuck at Delimiters pushing errors. If I remove Delimiters, running stored proc update queries are impossible (or am I missing something?).

Here is a sample content of an sql file I usually run:

```
USE 'iceberg';
DROP procedure IF EXISTS 'get_unpaidandduetickets';

DELIMITER $$
USE 'iceberg'$$
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'get_unpaidandduetickets'()
BEGIN

SELECT
    (SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(ticketid),0) FROM tickets WHERE balance > 0 AND status = 1) AS unpaidtickets
    ,(SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(ticketid),0) FROM tickets WHERE balance > 0 AND status = 1 AND DATE(duedate) = DATE(NOW())) AS dueticketstoday
    ,(SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(ticketid),0) FROM tickets WHERE balance > 0 AND status = 1 AND DATE(duedate) < DATE(NOW())) AS pastduetickets;

END$$

DELIMITER ;    

CALL set_databaseversion('001020181119');
```

Is there any way I could pull this off? I'm open to other means.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that you have connection string which contains the database name, it is unnecessary to append `USE 'iceberg';` and `DELIMITER $$` in the script because [`MySqlScript`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlScript.htm) instance can control the delimiter for you. Therefore, adjust your script contents as in example below:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS 'get_unpaidandduetickets'$$

CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'get_unpaidandduetickets'()
BEGIN
    -- procedure contents here
END$$

CALL set_databaseversion('001020181119')$$
```

Then, use [`ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) to read entire file contents as string and pass it into `Query` property inside `MySqlScript` instance:

```vb
' connection string example
' see connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/ for details
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=iceberg;Uid=UserID;Pwd=Password"

Using con As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim content As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("scriptfilename.sql")

    Dim sqlScript As New MySqlScript(con)

    sqlScript.Query = content   ' query string
    sqlScript.Delimiter = "$$"  ' delimiter setting
    sqlScript.Execute()

    ' other stuff
End Using
```

**Note:** You can create custom extension method which removes unnecessary parts such like `DELIMITER` and `USE` keywords.

Reference: [Using Delimiters with MySqlScript](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was on the impression that I still need to use Delimiters when executing command texts through .net when Deilimiters are exclusively used by Workbench.

Your answer has been very helpful!

Comment: Could you please update the Link in your answer !!!?